# retrieve the names depends upon the price conditions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table `product`:

```
product_id 
product_name
product_price
```

How can I retrieve the product name whose price range is:

```
1) 0-500
2) 500 - 1000
3) 1000+
```

Is it possible to retrieve the product name according to these conditions?

Comment: are you looking for 3 separate queries?

Comment: is it possible to write in single entity query for three conditions...

Comment: or is it possible to write seperate conditions....

Comment: many thanks for all your support....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming those are separate queries, and `price` is never negative:

```
var products1 = products.where(p=> p.product_price < 500);
var products2 = products.where(p=> p.product_price >=500 && p.product_price < 1000);
var products3 = products.where(p=> p.product_price >=1000);
```

I'm *including* the lower-value, but *excluding* the upper-value.

Answer (score 1):

```
var range1 = from p in products
        where p.product_price > 0 && product_price < 500
        select p;

var range2 = from p in products
        where p.product_price >= 500 && product_price < 1000
        select p;

var range3 = from p in products
        where p.product_price >= 1000
        select p;
```

Comment: I think you want "p.product_price"

Comment: not only p.product_price and i want all columns in product table

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest returning all results first, then separating them out.  Rather than making 3 separate queries to the database.

```
var prods =  (from p in products
             select p).ToList();

var range1 = from p in prods
             where p.product_price > 0 && p.product_price < 500
             select p;

var range2 = from p in prods
             where p.product_price >= 500 && p.product_price < 1000
             select p;

var range3 = from p in prods
             where p.product_price >= 1000
             select p;
```